# Inheritance scope using ui.router to filter data in ng-repeat [Angular1.5]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-filters

I have a problem probably with inheritance scope using ui.router. I'm creating a small application something like addressbook. I want to have an input in navbar which allow me to filter addresses on other page (so when i'm writing there, the parial view should be changed by ui-router). I have one view named index.html and other tamplets for each of sites using ui-ruter.

When i'm writing in input, view is changing, but the data is not filtered. I didn't receive any errors. Thanks for answers.
(Sorry for complicated description, its my first post)

index.html (without header with links)

```
<body  ng-app="appModule" ng-controller="applicationController">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-toggle">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand">Contact Manger</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-toggle">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a ui-sref="index">View</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="add">Add Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search" ng-keyup="startSearch()">
    </form>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <ui-view>
    </ui-view>
</div>
```

appModule.js

```
angular.module("appModule",[
"ui.router",
"AddModule",
"DetailsModule",
"MainModule",
"ngSanitize"])
```

appController.js

```
angular.module("appModule")
.controller('applicationController', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.startSearch = function(){
        $location.path('index');
    };
});
```

router.js

```
angular.module('appModule')
.config(function($stateProvider){ 

    $stateProvider.state('index',{
        url: '/index',
        template: "<main-component></main-component>"
    })
    .state('add',{
        url: '/add',
        template: "<add-component></add-component>"
    })
    .state('contact-details',{
        url: '/details/:id',
        template: "<details-component></details-component>",
    })
})
```

mainController.js (its in other module)

```
(function () {
    function MainController($scope, contactFactory) {
        $scope.contacts = contactFactory.get();
    }

    angular.module("MainModule")
    .component("mainComponent", {
        templateUrl: "/assets/partials/main.html",
        controller: ["$scope", "contactFactory", MainController],
    })
})()
```

And half of code in ui-router template:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:search">
        <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.phone}}</td>
        <td><a ui-sref="contact-details({id:$index})" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">More..</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you might know, `$scope` has prototype inheritance you can change your code to something like this:

just assign `search` to a property of an object on scope like this;

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.search = '';
```

your input changes to this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="data.search" ng-keyup="startSearch()">
```

and finally your inner component becomes like this:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:data.search">
        <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.phone}}</td>
        <td><a ui-sref="contact-details({id:$index})" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">More..</a></td>
    </tr>
```

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=29m19s) Misko discusses this issue more deeply.

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately it doesn't work for me, or I made something wrong. To main application controller I added $scope.data and $scope.data.search with empty initialization as in Your answer. Then changed "search" to "data.search".